# ISO8583 incoming message has fields with BCD encoded length of the field. How can I parse these fields with JPOS?

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I trying to rewrite ISO server from C# to Java and find out that fields of ISO message with variable lenght have ASCII encoding, but their length provided in BCD encoding.

Does JPOS have an instument to parse and store these type of fields in ISOMsg?

How it made in old c# server:

```
            FieldFormatters.Add( new StringFieldFormatter(
                62 /*field num*/, new VariableLengthManager( 0, 999, BcdLengthEncoder.GetInstance( 999 ) ),
                StringEncoder.GetInstance(), "Reserved for private use" ) );
```

and how I tried to do with JPOS.If I try with using ISO87APackager and ISO87BPackager:

```
...
 new IFA_LLLCHAR(999, "RESERVED PRIVATE"), /*62 or IFB_LLLCHAR*/
...
```

I'm getting an exception like this:

```
org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 62 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 3635 too long. Max: 999) unpacking field=62, consumed=55
```

**IFB_LLLCHAR** - ISOFieldPackager Binary LLLCHAR.
I think it isn't correct ISOFieldPackager in my case. What can I replace it with?

thanks in advance!

-------- update ----------

ok... the problem was in the wrong channel.

In my case I should use NACChannel, turns out I have network byte order.

Comment: Which packager configuration are you using?

Comment: I used ISO87APackage, but it doesn't work. I think I need to create custom packager.

Comment: If the length is in BCD you should probably use `ISO87BPackager` since `ISO87APackager` is for ASCII lengths. But if you have mixed fields, and in general to be sure you are aligned to your specs, is a good practice to use a custom packager, you can start checking field by field against the specs with [iso87binary.xml](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/resources/packager/iso87binary.xml)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the question a little to make it clearer. If I create custom packager, which ISOFieldPackager should I choose in my case?

Comment: Is better to use a `GenericPackager` and pass it the XML packager specification, and then attach a logger to it. The problem can come from a previous field

Comment: Can I see the parsing results for the previous fields (2-61) if the errors in 62?

Comment: Yes if you use `GenericPackager` and attach a logger to it